# Tumblr own page is not loading new pictures from posts

Tags: image, mobile-safari, loading, tumblr

My Tumblr page does not load new pictures from photoset on some occasions. I have experienced this issue on Safari browser. The page is supposed to work like a blog of pictures that are on a chaos (different width is set for each picture, so that every picture is shown differently). After first X pictures, the website is supposed to load a new one beneath them (same as facebook post are functioning for example). This works fine on most devices and browsers, but recently it has stopped working on Safari on iPhones (but only at some cases, one time it is working, but other time it is not). It does not even show the symbol of loading on the end of the page and basically nothing happens when user scrolls down to the end of the page.

I have tried to search for any hints or information of similar issues that other have, but cant find anything that would help. I have also tried to write to Tumblr support, but no answer there yet.

If any of you have any idea what might cause the problem, please, try to answer!

Comment: It would be useful to see some code. Can you share the link to your blog for a start?